# slide between different content/pages in libgdx

Tags: android, animation, libgdx

Is there an equivalent to page view controller in libgdx? This image shows a what I mean:

[image]

The 3 dots represent 3 different contents between which the user can choose. If user slides more than 1/2 of screens width, than content snaps to the next one. I am looking for a way to implement this in libgdx. Is there a class with similar functionality?

Comment: Not built in. But you could probably build one using ScrollPane and GestureListener.

Comment: Is there a github project on this topic already? :D

Comment: I have created something similar with a Table, 3 subwidgets (tabs) and clever input listener.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the code? Page controller would really be a nice feature in Scene2d framework.